# roslaunch mavros px4.launch not working properly

Tags: ros, mavlink, px4

when I run roslaunch mavros px4.launch command process start and shut down.

```
> ... logging to /home/yograj/.ros/log/77663396-f411-11e7-b93c-3c77e68de09b/roslaunch-yograj-Inspiron-5537-12518.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
>
> started roslaunch server http://yograj-Inspiron-5537:40223/
> 
> SUMMARY
>
> ========
> 
> CLEAR PARAMETERS
>
>  * /mavros/
> PARAMETERS
>
>  * /mavros/cmd/use_comp_id_system_control: False
>  * /mavros/conn/heartbeat_rate: 1.0
>  * /mavros/conn/system_time_rate: 1.0
>  * /mavros/conn/timeout: 10.0
>  * /mavros/conn/timesync_rate: 10.0
>  * /mavros/distance_sensor/hrlv_ez4_pub/field_of_view: 0.0
>  * /mavros/distance_sensor/hrlv_ez4_pub/frame_id: hrlv_ez4_sonar
>  * /mavros/distance_sensor/hrlv_ez4_pub/id: 0
>  * /mavros/distance_sensor/hrlv_ez4_pub/orientation: ROLL_180
>  * /mavros/distance_sensor/hrlv_ez4_pub/send_tf: True
>  * /mavros/distance_sensor/hrlv_ez4_pub/sensor_position/x: 0.0
>  * /mavros/distance_sensor/hrlv_ez4_pub/sensor_position/y: 0.0
>  * /mavros/distance_sensor/hrlv_ez4_pub/sensor_position/z: -0.1
>  * /mavros/distance_sensor/laser_1_sub/id: 3
>  * /mavros/distance_sensor/laser_1_sub/orientation: ROLL_180
>  * /mavros/distance_sensor/laser_1_sub/subscriber: True
>  * /mavros/distance_sensor/lidarlite_pub/field_of_view: 0.0
>  * /mavros/distance_sensor/lidarlite_pub/frame_id: lidarlite_laser
>  * /mavros/distance_sensor/lidarlite_pub/id: 1
>  * /mavros/distance_sensor/lidarlite_pub/orientation: ROLL_180
>  * /mavros/distance_sensor/lidarlite_pub/send_tf: True
>  * /mavros/distance_sensor/lidarlite_pub/sensor_position/x: 0.0
>  * /mavros/distance_sensor/lidarlite_pub/sensor_position/y: 0.0
>  * /mavros/distance_sensor/lidarlite_pub/sensor_position/z: -0.1
>  * /mavros/distance_sensor/sonar_1_sub/id: 2
>  * /mavros/distance_sensor/sonar_1_sub/orientation: ROLL_180
>  * /mavros/distance_sensor/sonar_1_sub/subscriber: True
>  * /mavros/fake_gps/eph: 2.0
>  * /mavros/fake_gps/epv: 2.0
>  * /mavros/fake_gps/fix_type: 3
>  * /mavros/fake_gps/geo_origin/alt: 408.0
>  * /mavros/fake_gps/geo_origin/lat: 47.3667
>  * /mavros/fake_gps/geo_origin/lon: 8.55
>  * /mavros/fake_gps/gps_rate: 5.0
>  * /mavros/fake_gps/mocap_transform: True
>  * /mavros/fake_gps/satellites_visible: 5
>  * /mavros/fake_gps/tf/child_frame_id: fix
>  * /mavros/fake_gps/tf/frame_id: map
>  * /mavros/fake_gps/tf/listen: False
>  * /mavros/fake_gps/tf/rate_limit: 10.0
>  * /mavros/fake_gps/tf/send: False
>  * /mavros/fake_gps/use_mocap: True
>  * /mavros/fake_gps/use_vision: False
>  * /mavros/fcu_url: udp://:14540@127....
>  * /mavros/gcs_url: 
>  * /mavros/global_position/child_frame_id: base_link
>  * /mavros/global_position/frame_id: map
>  * /mavros/global_position/rot_covariance: 99999.0
>  * /mavros/global_position/tf/child_frame_id: base_link
>  * /mavros/global_position/tf/frame_id: map
>  * /mavros/global_position/tf/global_frame_id: earth
>  * /mavros/global_position/tf/send: False
>  * /mavros/global_position/use_relative_alt: True
>  * /mavros/image/frame_id: px4flow
>  * /mavros/imu/angular_velocity_stdev: 0.000349065850399
>  * /mavros/imu/frame_id: base_link
>  * /mavros/imu/linear_acceleration_stdev: 0.0003
>  * /mavros/imu/magnetic_stdev: 0.0
>  * /mavros/imu/orientation_stdev: 1.0
>  * /mavros/local_position/frame_id: map
>  * /mavros/local_position/tf/child_frame_id: base_link
>  * /mavros/local_position/tf/frame_id: map
>  * /mavros/local_position/tf/send: False
>  * /mavros/local_position/tf/send_fcu: False
>  * /mavros/mission/pull_after_gcs: True
>  * /mavros/mocap/use_pose: True
>  * /mavros/mocap/use_tf: False
>  * /mavros/odometry/estimator_type: 3
>  * /mavros/odometry/frame_tf/desired_frame: ned
>  * /mavros/plugin_blacklist: ['safety_area', '...
>  * /mavros/plugin_whitelist: []
>  * /mavros/px4flow/frame_id: px4flow
>  * /mavros/px4flow/ranger_fov: 0.118682389136
>  * /mavros/px4flow/ranger_max_range: 5.0
>  * /mavros/px4flow/ranger_min_range: 0.3
>  * /mavros/safety_area/p1/x: 1.0
>  * /mavros/safety_area/p1/y: 1.0
>  * /mavros/safety_area/p1/z: 1.0
>  * /mavros/safety_area/p2/x: -1.0
>  * /mavros/safety_area/p2/y: -1.0
>  * /mavros/safety_area/p2/z: -1.0
>  * /mavros/setpoint_accel/send_force: False
>  * /mavros/setpoint_attitude/reverse_thrust: False
>  * /mavros/setpoint_attitude/tf/child_frame_id: target_attitude
>  * /mavros/setpoint_attitude/tf/frame_id: map
>  * /mavros/setpoint_attitude/tf/listen: False
>  * /mavros/setpoint_attitude/tf/rate_limit: 50.0
>  * /mavros/setpoint_attitude/use_quaternion: False
>  * /mavros/setpoint_position/mav_frame: LOCAL_NED
>  * /mavros/setpoint_position/tf/child_frame_id: target_position
>  * /mavros/setpoint_position/tf/frame_id: map
>  * /mavros/setpoint_position/tf/listen: False
>  * /mavros/setpoint_position/tf/rate_limit: 50.0
>  * /mavros/setpoint_velocity/mav_frame: LOCAL_NED
>  * /mavros/startup_px4_usb_quirk: True
>  * /mavros/sys/disable_diag: False
>  * /mavros/sys/min_voltage: 10.0
>  * /mavros/target_component_id: 1
>  * /mavros/target_system_id: 1
>  * /mavros/tdr_radio/low_rssi: 40
>  * /mavros/time/time_ref_source: fcu
>  * /mavros/time/timesync_avg_alpha: 0.6
>  * /mavros/time/timesync_mode: MAVLINK
>  * /mavros/vibration/frame_id: base_link
>  * /mavros/vision_pose/tf/child_frame_id: vision_estimate
>  * /mavros/vision_pose/tf/frame_id: map
>  * /mavros/vision_pose/tf/listen: False
>  * /mavros/vision_pose/tf/rate_limit: 10.0
>  * /mavros/vision_speed/listen_twist: False
>  * /rosdistro: kinetic
>  * /rosversion: 1.12.12
> 
> NODES
>   /
>     mavros (mavros/mavros_node)
> 
> ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
> 
> process[mavros-1]: started with pid [12536]
> [FATAL] [1515375213.809935923]: UAS: GeographicLib exception: File not readable /usr/share/GeographicLib/geoids/egm96-5.pgm | Run install_geographiclib_dataset.sh script in order to install Geoid Model dataset!
> 
> ================================================================================
> 
> REQUIRED process [mavros-1] has died!
> process has finished cleanly
> log file: /home/yograj/.ros/log/77663396-f411-11e7-b93c-3c77e68de09b/mavros-1*.log
> Initiating shutdown!
> 
> ================================================================================
> 
> [mavros-1] killing on exit
> shutting down processing monitor...
> ... shutting down processing monitor complete
> done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the source installation process as mentioned for [mavros](https://github.com/mavlink/mavros/blob/master/mavros/README.md) dependencies. And remaining problem solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960689/ubuntu-says-bash-program-permission-denied).

Answer (score 0):

There's an error at the end of the wall of text you pasted in that states,

> GeographicLib exception: File not readable /usr/share/GeographicLib/geoids/egm96-5.pgm
>
> **Run install_geographiclib_dataset.sh script in order to install Geoid Model dataset!**

Did you run that script?

Comment: I run                                                                                                                                                                            
 `./install_geographiclib_datasets.sh`                                                           
but it give                                                                                                              `bash: ./install_geographiclib_datasets.sh: Permission denied –`

Comment: you do not have the necessary permission to access the file. ... i suggest that you speak to your admin

Comment: I solved permission denied problem with the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960689/ubuntu-says-bash-program-permission-denied).